# How do I git reset --hard origin/whatever branch I have checked out?

Tags: git

I'm trying to write a git deployment script, but the script has to update several servers and they aren't all on the same Git branch.  Ideally the script should need just one command, to the effect of "git reset --hard origin/whateverBranchThisServerIsOn".

Now, I understand that I can do:

```
git reset --hard origin/foo
```

to reset my git environment to the remote foo branch.  However, what I'd like to do is reset to a remote branch, but not "foo" specifically, just "the remote of whatever branch the machine currently has checked out (ie. what branch shows up when you do `git branch`".

I've tried:

```
git reset --hard origin
```

and:

```
git reset --hard origin/HEAD
```

and:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

but they all either checkout other branches, or (in the last case) don't get the remote commits.  Surely there is some way to say `git reset --hard origin/CURRENT_BRANCH`?

Comment: So you basically want to rewrite history right? Undo your commits?

Comment: Not exactly, but that's the basic idea.  I'm trying to make a remote deployment script that says "`get fetch` (get all the remote commits); `git reset --hard origin/foo` (apply those commits)".  However, this script will be run against multiple servers, and one server is on the "foo" branch while another is on the "bar" branch, so I don't want to hardcode "foo" or "bar" in the "`git reset --hard origin/fooOrBar`" command.

Comment: I *could* just do `git pull`, and that command would respect which branch I've checked out.  However, if there's been any rebasing or anything on the branch, the pull might result in conflicts, and I don't want to be resolving conflicts on a remote system; I just want the remote system to use what's in git (for whatever branch it has checked out).  So `git reset --hard` seems like the command I want ... if I could only get it to respect my checked-out-branch the way `git pull` does.

Comment: Can you edit your question to say more about the specific thing you want to do (as you've added in the comments above)?  You might get more helpful answers that way.  There might be a better way to do what you're wanting to do.

Comment: How about `remotes/origin/HEAD` ?  Really haven't done any git scripting at all yet, but on the command line, you could use `git branch -av --contains HEAD`.

If you don't care about local changes, you could also use `git checkout` instead of `git reset`.

Comment: Since Andy's `HEAD@{upstream}` works great, and I've already wasted enough time on this issue, I'll leave experimenting with `remotes/origin/HEAD` to anyone else who wants to do so (and comment back here).

Comment: Oh, and while I don't care about keeping changes (in fact, I'm specifically trying to lose them, if they exist at all), git checkout has the same "I need to know which branch I'm on" problem as reset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of "the branch I have checked out" is a little malformed.  There is no 1:1 relationship between branches like that.  Your branch may not have an "origin" at all.  But it can have a remote tracking branch, which may (or may not) have the same name as the one you are on.  Reading `man gitrevisions`, it looks specifying `HEAD@{upstream}` should work to do what you want.  But I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 3):

```
# simple script to reset hard to the current branch origin
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short -q  HEAD)
echo "Sure to reset hard to origin/$branch ?"
read
git reset --hard origin/$branch
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | xargs -I {} git reset --hard origin/{}
```

worked for me, it's a bit long though

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using the fantastic [oh my zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) - it already comes with an alias `groh` that does exactly that:

```
groh='git reset origin/$(git_current_branch) --hard'
```

Answer (score 0):

"Whatever you currently have checked out" goes by the name `HEAD`. So, `git reset --hard HEAD` will revert you to whatever you had checked out before you started making modifications that you have now decided you don't want to keep...

Since the branch you're currently on may or may not have an upstream equivalent, I'm not sure there's a single command to blindly achieve what you're describing. You could write a bit of a shell script that parses the output from `git branch` and makes a decision on which remote branch you want to be on, or dies if it sees something it doesn't expect.

Comment: Wow, so there's really no way to say "git reset --hard origin/*currentBranch*" in Git?

Comment: "git reset --hard" is the same as "git reset --hard HEAD"

Comment: @machineghost I wouldn't put it quite that way - there *is* a way to do it, but it's not one simple command. You need to figure out a) what branch am I currently on, b) what branch, if any, on the remote repo does this branch correspond to (keep in mind the names don't even have to resemble each other) and then use both those branch names to decide whether resetting makes sense. The best way is to have the local branch track the remote branch, then `git pull` will "do the right thing" when you're on that branch (at least in the fast-forward case).

Comment: @sjakubowski Correct, but unfortunately neither of those are what I want to do; `git reset -hard HEAD` sets things back to the *local* version, whereas I want to reset things back to the *origin* version.

Comment: @sjakubowski Right, and I don't foresee that default ever changing, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit about what you are requesting... I've had to clean up a few too many messes caused by assumptions that changed for one reason or other...